# How to enter data in sql table using loop

Tags: sql, database, sqlplus

I created a table in sqlplus using

```
create table employee(id number(1) primary key, name varchar(5));
```

then I wanted to enter data into table using loop so I implemented

```
  SQL> begin    
  2  for i in 1..4
  3  loop
  4  insert into employee       
  5  values(i, '&name');
  6  end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /
```

It showed me a prompt to enter name once

```
Enter value for name: a
```

Instead of running for 4 times and asking to input name everytime it just ran once.
After checking the output, I found my table as

```
SQL> select * from employee;

    ID NAME
---------- ----
     1 a
     2 a
     3 a
     4 a
```

I want to enter different names for every employee id, not the same name for all the customer.

Comment: I'm not an sqlplus expert - but normally you'd do something like multiple inserts.. And let database assign id's for you. If you were coding this for integration with a programming language you'd normally have prepared (parameterised) statements to execute that did the insert, with some sort of web front end or a GUI. Then control the looping/input in the programming language of choice... .NET/Python/Java etc.

Comment: It is not possible to repeatedly prompt in a PL/SQL loop.